# Piping search term from clipboard (not filename) to grep to search a folder

Tags: grep, clipboard, xsel

I am trying to use `xsel` clipboard to pipe search term to `grep` to search in folder full of txt files. Can anybody suggest a method to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `grep` implementations that support of `-r` option for recursive `grep`:

```
grep -rFe "$(xsel -b -o)" /path/to/your/folder
```

For other `grep` implementations, use `find` to look up the files:

```
find /path/to/your/folder -type f -exec \
  grep -Fe "$(xsel -b -o)" /dev/null {} +
```

The `/dev/null` is to make sure at least 2 file names are passed to `grep` so `grep` always prints the name of the files the strings are found in.

Note that if the CLIPBOARD selection contains more than one line, each line will be searched separately. For instance, if the selection contains `a<newline>b`, it will report lines that contain `a` or `b` (or both).

To match on `a<newline>b` instead, you could use `pcregrep` with its multiline mode:

```
pcregrep -rM "\Q$(xsel -b -o | sed 's/\\E/&\\&\\Q/g'; printf '\\E')" /path/to/folder
```

Comment: With `GNU grep`, option `-H` can be used instead of `/dev/null`... not sure about other versions...

Comment: @Sundeep, yes that's a GNU extension. IOW, `grep` implementations that have `-H` also have `-r`.